# Image stretching on mobile phone orientation change

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, orientation

I made an ad slider for a web project. I used the basic jQuery slider from www.basic-slider.com. And it allowed me to set the following in the JavaScript file:

```
$('#banner-fade-left').bjqs({
    height      : 482,
    width       : 482,
    responsive  : true,
```

The width of the divs containing the ads was set to 50%.

```
<div style="max-width:50%; float:left">
    <div id="banner-fade-left">
        <ul><li>AD HERE</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
 <div style="max-width:50%; float:left">
    <div id="banner-fade-left">
        <ul><li>AD HERE</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The links and the images inside the divs were formatted this way:

```
li.bjqs-slide a {
height: auto !important;
width: auto;
}

li.bjqs-slide a img {
height: auto !important;
width: 100%;    
}
```

The output is 2 banners with a 482px width placed side by side on the page. (see www.solaire.com)

[image: ads]

The image stretching problem occurs when the website is viewed on a mobile browser. At first load **(portrait view)**, the dimensions of the ads are correct. But when you change the orientation of the phone to **landscape**, this happens:

[image: image stretched on landscape view]

As you can see, the images look compressed horizontally.
When you change it to portrait again, the image is stretched out:

[image: image stretched on landscape view]

The height is set to **auto !important** and the width is set to 100% to always occupy the entire div. But it seems that the height doesn't always adjust properly relative to the width of the image. The image keeps on stretching every time the orientation changes. The same thing actually happens on a desktop browser when you rapidly adjust the width of the browser.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media queries in your css like this:

```
    @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}
```

or in your javascript file:

```
   var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)");
if (mql.matches){
```